# How to store large amounts of data using php

Tags: mysql, json, database, database-design

Most of the websites (including the one I wanted to do) let you customise the website for better user experience. However, that would result in storing a lot of things in the database. I have researched how to do so without overloading the database but I can't seem to find a correct or optimum solution.

**Solution 1:**

Store everything in a database. However, as I had said, that would result in the table having more than 50 columns but databases are designed for heavy dutys so I'm not sure if it is a good idea or not.

**Solution 2:**

Using the first solution but break everything into different tables. The problem for this is that I would normally spend lots of times checking all the tables and I also think that this is not a good idea too.

**Final Solution:** 

Store everything in a json file. I had thought of this but is it secure enough? I am not storing the user's sensitive information in the json files so I think that it is not that much point in hacking the files. I think that I can store the user's preferences here and store the file name in the user's database entry.

I only found these ways so which solution is better or is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Look into "relational database design". .... Preferences and such on the other hand might be tied to specific users, and as such makes sense if they were in a db of some kind too. Whereas JSON is more of a protocol in my opinion, and would be suitable for communication from backend to frontend (and vice versa), and for datasets that are static and not too large.

Comment: I think you have to learn how to develop databases right way based on proven solutions.

Comment: "Storing a lot of things" -- More than a billion things?  Even that won't necessarily "overload the database".  "More than 50 columns" -- Do not store an array of things across columns; use extra tables.  "Lots of time checking all the tables" -- Need more details to comment on this.  JSON -- Only for miscellany that you don't need to serach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, forget about storing big data in a json file. It will be really slow with much data, because there are no indexes.

You should definitely use a Database. Using "Subtables" is no Problem at all. So I would go with solution 2.

I think you should learn more about [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) and [MySQL optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html). It's really not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at database structure maintained with in wordpress. You may get the idea of polymorphic relation and good relation database design.

I can not say to go with particular solution. If you ask me then I would prefer to make use of JSON datatype in database(JSON datatype supported only in latest versions of mysql probably 5.7+). I would include all common column name in table while optional column names (you can set dynamic columns name as you need .. I think your real problem is defining all possible columns names that might be required) and their values will be stored in column which has json datatype. I am using following pattern -

`id,  post_title,  post_short_description,  url, meta_tags, meta_description,  post_category_id, custom_filed_values,  image, custom_field_values, content`

You can create other table just separating `custom_field_values, content` with one to one relationship.